# How to iterate over a node list and get child elements?

Tags: java, xml, xmlnode, nodelist

I have some XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <lname>xxxx</lname>
    <fname>yyyy</fname>
    <address>
        <city>zzzz</city>
        <state>ffff</state>
        <country>aaaa</country>
    <address>
    <dob>xx-xx-xxxx</dob>
    <familymembers>
        <father>
            <fname>bbbb</fname>
            <lname>dddd</lname>
        </father>
        <mother>
            <fname>zzzz</fname>
            <lname>aaaa</lname>
        </mother>
        <sibling>
            <fname>bbbb</fname>
            <lname>dddd</lname>
        </sibling>
    </familymembers>
</person>
```

My requirement is that all child elements should be traversed and placed inside a map as key-value pairs like this:

```
persion.version --> 1.1
persion.lname --> xxxx
persion.fname --> yyyy
person.address.city --> zzzz
person.address.state --> ffff
person.address.country --> aaaa
person.familymembers.father.fname --> bbbb
person.familymembers.father.lname --> dddd
person.familymembers.mother.fname --> zzzz
person.familymembers.mother.lname --> aaaa
person.familymembers.sibling.fname --> bbbb
person.familymembers.sibling.lname --> dddd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jdom or dom4j to parse xml file,you can easily have this work done.